# ssl not working in vsftpd; write:errno=32

Tags: openssl, ssl, vsftpd

this is what i have tried:

```
1) vsftpd.pem created using the following self-signed certificate: 
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout $certname -out $certname -days 365
2) owner/permissions: root/0600
3) vsftpd config:
pam_service_name=vsftpd
ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
#ssl_ciphers=HIGH
ssl_ciphers=TLSv1.2
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40010
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_root=/srv/ftp
anon_upload_enable=NO
chroot_local_user=NO
ftpd_banner=Welcome message
idle_session_timeout=900
log_ftp_protocol=YES
max_clients=10
max_per_ip=3
pasv_enable=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
debug_ssl=YES
```

I know all the configurations are correct; i can't seem to find what the issue is. This is what i get when i run the following command (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx represent the local IP address, i have also tried using localhost, result is the same):

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21 -showcerts -starttls ftp
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=32
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 72 bytes and written 10 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1561132486
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

When i run strace, i get the following at the beginning:

```
strace /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
sapr3pr:/etc/ssl/private # strace /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
execve("/usr/sbin/vsftpd", ["/usr/sbin/vsftpd", "/etc/vsftpd.conf"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x55a42f75a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7faf6a044000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=120628, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 120628, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faf6a026000
close(3)                                = 0
```

'No such file or directory' !!?? what does that mean? 
the path to the file created is correct in the config file:

config file:

```
ls -ltrha /etc/ssl/private/
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   72 Feb 25  2018 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Jun 21 11:40 vsftpd.pem -> 20190621_CERT.pem
drwx------ 1 root root   90 Jun 21 11:40 .
-rw------- 1 root root 5.4K Jun 21 11:43 20190621_CERT.pem
```

note: softlink or direct link produce the same results.

would greatly appreciate some input. Thanks.

Comment: does the `openssl s_client` command  work if you connect to port 990?

Comment: why do you want me to check port 990? the issue is not the port. i have a similar server with the same configs and it is functional.

Comment: strace line you focused on has nothing to do with error you have

Comment: please, do explain

Comment: it is normal that syscalls returning errors, often that is expected. I suspect (with 95% probability) that you look into strace log, found first error and decided that it has something to do with your problem, that is mistake. Look onto tail of your strace not beginning. Launch any other app (for example ls) and I am pretty sure you'll see same 'error'.

Comment: you are correct regarding that error message, so the tail gives me this:

bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(21), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 32)                           = 0
accept(3,